# Enforcing Schema using .as[A] doesn't enforce the type

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset

I'm trying to read a table in SQL Server, and then I want to enforce the schema of what I read. So I defined:

`case class WhatIWant(FieldA: String, FieldB: String)`

Then I try to do a regular spark read from SQL server, the Dataframe I read back, is with type of:

```
input:org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
    FieldA:integer
    FieldB:String
```

then I appended `.as[WhatIWant]` when I read, I thought this would make it a `Dataset[WhatIWant]` with the typing information as I defined. Turns out, in the notebook, it will actually give me:

```
intput:org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[WhatIWant]
    FieldA:integer
    FieldB:String
```

Now I'm confused on two things:

1. Will `.as[]` actually enforce the schema if the schema inferred in Dataframe is different than the definition of the case class?
2. I was under the assumption Dataset is strongly typed. But the typing info I got from the Databricks notebook is actually not the same as what I defined. Is there an explanation of this?

Quick note:
All the values for "FieldA" are nulls, I felt like that played a part in this, but I'm still confused.

Comment: Reading from a Relational Store follows the schema defined in the required table's DDL. If you want you can pass a **query** parameter to SparkConf with the SQL Server query as its value and Spark would run the query on the database to fetch the results.

Comment: the method **as[]** will take effect only if you create a CustomEncoder for your Case Class and make it implicitly available in the file where you are running the command to read the data from SQL Server into a DataFrame